# Can we exclude obscenity from review audits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, review-audits

I just had a [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6968981) that contained nothing but the obscene word

> fuck (See [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28107921/revisions))

repeated over and over. I wasn't particularly offended by this, but as an audit it seemed unnecessary. Is it reasonable to remove the especially obscene edits from the audit options?

Comment: Just making sure you're still awake! >_> <_<

Comment: This has the same problems as automatically filtering posts for profanity: in times of unicode characters and other tricks, it's just impossible to reliably filter all possible spellings of "offensive" words. There's a great meta post about this which I can't find right now. One could do a "best effort" filtering, but it's questionable if that's worth the effort.

Comment: @l4mpi: well, you could exclude all straight *offensive* content (those posts that got 6 straight offensive flags). But that'd not do anything useful, as there still would be *real* offensive posts in the review queue (e.g. not audits).

Comment: 'PHP PHP PHP PHP PHP PHP....'

Comment: @MartinJames It's recursively recursive! (PHPHypertextPreprocessor)HPHypertextPreprocessor ...

Comment: recursive curse?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it would be useful (if you consider seeing less profanity useful) because reducing or eliminating the possibility of offensive _audits_ probably greatly reduces the possibility of seeing an offensive post in review at all. As in, we can't "protect" anybody from seeing profanity in the review queue, but we don't have to shove it into their faces. But as I said, I don't think it's fixable or even a problem worth fixing.

Comment: I think that bad words should be removed, and at least make people go through the effort of trying to hide them with Unicode.  In any event, life is hard enough w/o getting sweared at in a post.

Comment: @JosephDoggie: You might want to re-read [this comment about the impossiblity of getting it right](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285518/can-we-exclude-obscenity-from-review-audits#comment152299_285518), and maybe try to track down the full MSE post, if that seems insufficient explanation.

Comment: Actually I did -- hence the "at least make people go through the effort of trying to hide them with Unicode" which was inspired by that very post.  But thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, I don't think we should do that.

Note that if that were a *real* post, not an audit, you'd still have to deal with the offensive post. That is partly *why* we review, to keep trash like that out.

Censoring the audits is not going to remove the possibility that obscenity would show up in your reviews *anyway*, but at the same time you'd never be trained on such trash either.

In other words, if you don't want to see any offensive trash, don't review.

Comment: It's only because it was an audit, I considered it differently. For a real review or if I had just stumbled across it, I would have simply flagged it.

Comment: @JamesWebster: why are audits suddenly special here then?

Comment: I'm.... not sure. :P